# Local Variable or Static Variable or Global Variable

Tags: c

**In recursive function, the variable should be declared as local or static or global variable?**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which variable? What's the code look like? I'm going to guess not global.

Comment: Isn't that a homework question?

Comment: The OP has asked 7 questions so far and all the accepted answers were from Abhineet Agarwal. Interesting :)

Comment: Hi "gameover" if u think that u r smart then u r wrong, bcz i accept what i feel is best. And till now he has helped me a lot right from the beginning when i have joined this site.

Comment: lol :P looks like we got a detective amongst us(gameover). y u so defensive priya?? he is jus joking.

Comment: Nw if hel wants to help me also, he will not come to help me as somebody has told which can hurt someone ego. – Priya 9 mins ago

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends. A static variable means you have one variable that's shared across all recursive invocations. A normal local variable means each recursive invocation gets its own copy of that variable. You need to choose the one that makes sense for what you're doing.

A global is like a static local variable (one variable shared by all invocations) but it's also visible to the rest of the application.

Comment: I would add that using global variables is bad programming style. No matter where and how they are being used. Static variables may also cause bugs that are tricky to understand.

Comment: ... *especially* in recursive functions.

Answer (score 2):

Local only.

The recursion method can be defined in a way that passes it's variables with each call. And the final return value is calculated using previous recursion return vars. such as return `rec(i-1)+rec(i-2)`

If you use global variables, if you run parallel two or more recursion the variables can be messed up.

I advise you to write your recursion to use local variables and in params only.

Comment: Lol, looks like you wandered into a maelstrom of confusion…

Answer (score 0):

Using a local variable, you would have to pass this along and return with each recursive call.

Static and global variables can be reached from within any level of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

U can use any of the mentioned ones but everything depends on what u supposed to with recursion !!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do. Usually I would avoid static.